# How to add "content-type" header in soap webservice

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, android-ksoap2

I've seen several different examples and I can't get any to work. My goal is to add a content type of JSON to my request. Without the header, my request doesn't error:

```
  public void calculate() {
        String SOAP_ACTION = "http://----/--";
        String METHOD_NAME = "----";
        String NAMESPACE = "http://-----/";
        String URL = "http://----/---/----.asmx";
        try {
            // Creating a new empty SOAP message object

            SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            Request.addProperty("username", "***");
            Request.addProperty("password", "****");
            SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
            soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

            HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);


            transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);

            resultString = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();

            Log.i(TAG, "Result Celsius: " + resultString);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
// Create a of HeaderProperty
List<HeaderProperty> headerList = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
// Add Content-Type to the list
headerList.add(new HeaderProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8"));

// Pass this list as 3rd argument to call method
transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope, headerList);
```